# How to bind button function to a corresponding item in an array - AJAX, Firebase

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, firebase

I'm attempting to first make an AJAX request from a social API and append the results with a button inside the div that will save the corresponding item in the array to my firebase database.  For example,

I have my AJAX request - I cut out about 75% of the actual code that isn't needed for the question.

```
 $.ajax({
          type : 'GET',
          url : url,
            dataType : "jsonp",
            cache: false,
         success : function(data){
         console.debug(data);
         vids = data.response.items;

      for(var i in vids) {

        dataTitle = vids[i].title;

        ncode = "<div class='tile'><img src='"+ vids[i].title "'/></a><button class='btn' type='button' onClick='saveToDatabase()'>Save</button></div>";

        $('#content').append( ncode )
```

And then I have my function that I want to save the 'title' of the object the button was appended with to the firebase database.

```
var dataTitle;

function saveToDatabase() { 
 ref.push({
    title: dataTitle
  });  
}
```

The issue is that when the button is clicked it posts a random title from inside the array instead of the title of the item the button was appended with... How can I bind the buttons function to the correct dataTitle?

I'm not sure if that makes sense so please let me know if clarification is needed.  Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: try passing an argument to `saveToDatabase` function

Comment: Could you provide an example of what that would look like?  I tried passing the argument but dataTitle is still undefined? Would it not look like this?

onClick="saveToDatabase(\'' + dataTitle + '\')"

Comment: This is extremely broken. Worst of all, I suspect you're taking unsanitized content from an external source and putting it into URL links--a recipe for XSS. Slightly less important, but the root cause of probably 90% of your issues, the point of jQuery is to abstract the logic from your presentation, thus you shouldn't be manually writing `src` and `onClick` events here. You should be using jQuery for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fails because you are iterating the entire list and assigning them to a global variable. The result is not random at all--it's the last item in the list, which was the last to be assigned to the globar variable.

Try using jQuery rather than writing your own DOM events, and utilize a closure to reference the video title.

```
function saveToDatabase(dataTitle) { 
 ref.push({
    title: dataTitle
  });  
}

$.ajax({
  type : 'GET',
  url : url,
  dataType : "jsonp",
  cache: false,
  success : function(data) {
    console.debug(data); // console.debug not supported in all (any?) versions of IE
    buildVideoList(data.response.items);
  }
});

function buildVideoList(vids) {
  $.each(vids, function(vid) {
    var $img = $('<img></img>');
    $img.attr('src', sanitize(vid.title));

    var $button = $('<button class="btn">Save</button>');
    $button.click(saveToDatabase.bind(null, vid.title));

    $('<div class="tile"></div>')
      .append($img)
      .append($button)
      .appendTo('#content');
  });
}

// rudimentary and possibly ineffective, just here to
// point out that it is necessary
function sanitize(url) {
  return url.replace(/[<>'"]/, '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually just ended up passing the index to the function by creating a global array like so. It seems to be working fine... any reason I shouldn't do it this way?

```
var vids = []; //global 

function foo() {
 $.ajax({
          type : 'GET',
          url : url,
            dataType : "jsonp",
            cache: false,
         success : function(data){
         console.debug(data);
         vids = data.response.items;

      for(var i in vids) {

        ncode = "<div class='tile'><img src='"+ vids[i].title "'/></a><button class='btn' type='button' onClick='saveToDatabase('+i+')'>Save</button></div>";

        $('#content').append( ncode )
} //end ajax function

function saveToDatabase(i) { 
 ref.push({
    title: vids[i].title
  });  
}
```